# Google maps for android not showing till I open the inbuilt maps application

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am trying build an application which shows maps in my application. Everything works fine once I open the in built maps app and go back to my app else it does not display the maps just the logo at the bottom.

Steps I follow.

1. Generate signed APK install it on device. launch app, no maps.
2. minimize then launch in built maps and minimize (close it does not matter)
3. maximize my app and it works. I can even see calls from the API manager in console.developers.google.com

How do I figure out what the problem is? please help with the issue.

EDIT 1:

If I create a new sample application and use the default map activity in a sample appliation and paste my key and fire it up also the same behavior. I have changed nothing in the application except for pasting the key.

Device is moto g3 running lollipop

Comment: have you checked your logcat when the activity with the map starts?

Comment: Turns out every application has the same problem .... Uninstalled UBER and reinstalled it, had to open the maps and then voila maps on UBER works... Guess something to do with lollipop and Motorola... Tested it on other phones and it works fine ... Onward we go thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out every application has the same problem .... Uninstalled UBER and reinstalled it, had to open the maps and then voila maps on UBER works... Guess something to do with lollipop and Motorola... Tested it on other phones and it works fine. Check if any other application which uses maps also acts up like this.